# MATLAB help content for an abstract method

Tags: matlab, documentation

In ordinary class methods I can supply content for the "help" command in MATLAB. However, when writing an abstract method, the help function does not see the abstract methods. For example, if you have a class NeedsHelp:

```
classdef NeedsHelp
    methods (Abstract)
        INeedHelp(self)
        % This method is not visible to the help command.
    end
    methods
        function IHaveHelp(self)
            % This method shows help as expected.
        end
    end
end
```

The help command acts as follows (R2009b):

```
>> help NeedsHelp.IHaveHelp
  This method shows help as expected.

>> help NeedsHelp.INeedHelp

NeedsHelp.INeedHelp not found.
```

Are there any solutions to providing documentation for abstract methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is not possible as of R2009b, according to Loren's blog at The MathWorks. See [this comment and her reply](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/06/07/publishing/#comment-30683).

Answer (score 5):

Put the help **before** the function line for abstract methods, just like you do for properties. I don't have 9b to test, but in 11b:

```
classdef NeedsHelp
    methods (Abstract)
        % Help goes here.
        INeedHelp(self)
    end
end

>> help NeedsHelp.INeedHelp
  Help goes here.
```

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into this problem. You can't do this in the actual class definition. There is a work-around (at least in 2012b) by using the fact that you can put [Methods in Different Files](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/specifying-methods-and-functions.html#brqy3km-15) and [Class Precedence and MATLAB Path](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/organizing-classes-in-folders.html#brfynrp-4).

For the example, say you have your class file saved as

```
C:\myPath\NeedsHelp.m
```

To add the help file for the abstract method, first create a folder within the directory (myPath) which has the name of the class preceded by the @-symbol (@NeedsHelp). Within this folder create an M-File with the name of the abstract method (INeedHelp.m).

```
C:\myPath\@NeedsHelp\INeedHelp.m
```

This M-file contains only the "help" documentation. Because of the way class precedence works, the concrete methods of a subclass methods will be called, but when no "help" documentation is found, the @-folder is searched for a method definition.

The "help" documentation is inherited by both abstract and concrete subclasses and can be overwritten by both. Note that you don't have to put your class into the @-folder for this to work properly for the purpose of documentation.

(This is basically the way the "help" documentation is provided for built-in functions).